# The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using Asp.Net core 3.1

I have implemented a functionality to download Excel/CSV file by writing data to HttpContext Response and I am able to download the file but I get error log saying

```html
[ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. (48a46595)
System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
```

Also I deployed my application on the server and get error code 502.

Below is the code.

```html
public static class IWorkBookExtensions
    {
        public static void WriteExcelToResponse(this IWorkbook book, HttpContext httpContext, string templateName, ILogger<ExportDataController> _logger)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = httpContext.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateName))
                {
                    var contentDisposition = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                    contentDisposition.SetHttpFileName(templateName);
                    response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();
                }
                book.Write(response.Body);
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.ToString() + ex.Message);
            }
           
        }
     }
```

Below is the error log

```html
2020-10-13T14:45:17.1452752-05:00 80003b-00-fc00-3f-84967bb [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. (48a46595)
System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.ThrowIfReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.set_Item(String key, StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   2020-10-13T14:45:17.1546662-05:00 80003b-00-fc00-3f-84967bb [WRN] The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be executed. (e1dd4c0d)
2020-10-13T14:45:17.2073595-05:00 880003b-00-fc00-3f-84967bb [ERR] Connection ID ""18300129210426"", Request ID ""80003b-00-fc00-3f-84967bb"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. (bf3147)
System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
```

Comment: What is IWorkbook.Write doing?

Comment: Hello @MikeJ, I used it to write data to the excel file.

Comment: @MikeJ, I removed IWorkbook.Write and I can still download the file but I cannot open the excel file. Error message "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid.

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear enough.  It sounds like the code inside IWorkbook.Write may be the source of the problems.  Is that something you created?

Comment: This means what it says. If the response has already been sent to the user, you can't modify the headers anymore, they have already gone out.Can you show the code you call this method?

Comment: I tried your code and it works well. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMlwm.gif)